# Good way of accessing "upper class" methods inside a nested class?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a program:

```js
class Program {
  constructor() {
    this.profileManager = new ProfileManager();
  }
  
  saveProgramConfig() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

If something happens inside `ProfileManager`, and it needs to save the program configuration, what would be the best way of accessing this specific instance's `saveProgramConfig` method from inside the `ProfileManager` class?

Comment: why not to use inheritence?

Comment: I thought by doing `ProfileManager extends Program`, by creating a new `ProfileManager` instance, it would also create a new `Program` instance (parent class of ProfileManager), but I need ProfileManager to access the methods of this specific `Program` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the instance as an argument so that both instances have a link to each other:

```
this.profileManager = new ProfileManager(this);
```

and have ProfileManager save the instance to one of its own properties, and call `saveProgramConfig` on it when needed.

Comment: So I would just do `this.profileManager = new ProfileManager(this)` inside the Program constructor? That's what I've been doing, I just thought there could have been a better way (or I'm doing it wrong)

Comment: It works - sometimes it's a good solution, but in my experience, having these sort of classes in the first place is often a sign something isn't quite structurally right (IMO).

Comment: I see, do you have any suggestions on how you would structure something like this that I don't fall into any bad software design traps?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish, every situation is different. At least in my experience, I've always found plain functions and plain objects to make more sense when writing code, but others may prefer differently.

Comment: I understand, I may have overcorrected by steering clear of OOP in Javascript and then by actually trying it, promptly made literally everything a class, thank you! it works and doesn't blow up in my face (as of now)

Comment: Classes *are* OOP, mostly. If you want to steer clear of it (which is just fine, it's what I do as well), avoid classes. If you want OOP, use classes.

Comment: Oh no, i know, it's just that for the past few years I've intentionally avoided them, and now I want to try using them in a project (which is what I meant when I said i over-corrected), thank you for your answer! much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What the issue with the following approach? you can access the test method of Program inside ProfileManager class.

```
 class Program  {
       test() {
         return "Hello World";
    }
 }

class ProfileManager  extends Program  {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  
  main() {
    return this.test();
  }
}

const tp = new B;
console.log(tp.main());
```

Comment: What if I not only have `ProfileManager` that manages program profile, but also `DownloadManager` which manages current downloads? If both extend Program class, wouldn't that mean by saying `new ProfileManager` & `new DownloadManager` I would also create two `Program` classes (inherited by the two)? I only need one `Program` instance running.

Comment: Didn't understood..? why you will have to create two Program classes. If so you can extends DownloadManager in ProfileManager class and then extends the ProfileManager in Program so you will have access to both programManager and DownloadManager. Why you will have to write 2 classes?

Comment: `DownloadManager` and `ProfileManager` are two separate "features" inside this theoretical Program. They don't really have a connection with each other and there is only one of them for each `Program` instance. So I didn't think inheritance would work, as creating a DownloadManager & ProfileManager would mean I would create two Program classes instead (because both Managers extend the Program class), I just need them to be under this specific `Program` instance.